# how to save synonyms in database ( Oracle Text )

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I am using oracle text for Arabic language.

I want to save the synonyms list in a database table, so the domain index read from this table, any idea ?

Comment: You mean you want to create synonyms in arabic language which reference to original (english perhaps ?)  tables ?

Comment: no sir, I want to store each arabic word with it synonyms in a table, so when I search my text, it searched the text with those synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :

1- I uploaded my synonyms list to a table called words( contains all the terms and their synonyms' IDs ) and master table called synset (contains synonyms)

2- create thesaurus :

```
begin
  ctx_thes.create_thesaurus ('MyThesaurus');
end;
```

3- create a stored procedure to read from my table [words] and create relationship between synonyms:

```
create or replace procedure CreateSynonyms is
  CURSOR syn_cur is    select s.name_abstract,w.root,w.word_abstract 
  from p words  w , synset s 
  where w.synset_id=s.synset_id and w.root<>s.name_abstract and w.word_abstract<> s.name_abstract
  order by s.synset_id;
  syn_rec syn_cur%rowtype;
BEGIN
OPEN syn_cur;
LOOP
  FETCH syn_cur into syn_rec;
  EXIT WHEN syn_cur%notfound;
  begin
    ctx_thes.create_relation ('MyThesurus', syn_rec.name_abstract, 'syn', syn_rec.word_abstract);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

4- rewrite my query to select synonyms:

```
select  /*+ FIRST_ROWS(1)*/  sentence_id,score(1) as sc, isn  
          where contains(PROCESSED_TEXT,'<query>
<textquery>
   search for somthing here
 <progression>
 <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS,  "{", "}", ","))</rewrite></seq>
 <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS,  "syn(", ",listing)", " , "))</rewrite>/seq>
 </progression>
 </textquery>
 <score datatype="INTEGER" algorithm="COUNT"/></query>',1)>0
```

Hope this will help someone